# Hit a curb. Rim scratched up bad. Any damage other than rim do you think?

Tags: tires, wheels

[image]
Do you think there could be more damage other than the rim being scratched?

Comment: Did you slide into a curb or just drive to close to it?

Comment: That's some serious curb rash :o)

Comment: Given the acute angle which the curb interacted with the wheel, it doesn't appear to have damaged the bead of the tire in any way. While not quite as good as new, I highly doubt it will have damaged the structural integrity of the wheel, and it's probably safe to keep driving on it.

Comment: "Do you think there could be more damage other then the rim scratched" No, but my xray vision is not working right now,

Comment: The front wheel alignment could have been altered, which is something you may not notice until you're driving at freeway speeds. If you're interested in repairing this damage, check out KwickSilver.

Answer (score 1):

I damaged a wheel once, it did not look nearly as bad as the picture. The wheel was bent and could not be balanced although one could not see the gradual bend (After I had ground and polished the aluminum wheel).